# I want to know how to write an update script for Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

I want to know how to write the mongodb script for updating the field in my db

my collection is something like this

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: xyz,
  answer: [
            { type: 'C',
              from: 0
             },
            { type: 'M',
              from: 0 
            },
           { type: 'P',
              from: 0 
            }
........ so on
          ]
}
.
.
.
and other objects
```

I want to add a field called "test" in each object of answer array whose "type" value is not 'C'

I am new to this. Can someone help me how should i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
db.col.updateOne(
   { name: "xyz" },
   { "$set": { 'answer.$[i].test': null } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ "i.type": { $ne: "C" } }] }
)
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "name" : "xyz", 
    "answer" : [
        {
            "type" : "C", 
            "from" : 0.0
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "M", 
            "from" : 0.0, 
            "test" : null
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "P", 
            "from" : 0.0, 
            "test" : null
        }
    ]
}
```

If you like to update all documents in your collection use `updateMany()` and skip filter `{ name: "xyz" }`

Of course you can run the update manually like this:

```
db.col.find().forEach(function (doc) {
   doc.answer.forEach(function (i) {
      if (i.type != "C")
         i.test = null;
   })
   db.col.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id },
      { $set: doc }
   )
})
```

but you have to admit, `arrayFilters` is shorter and more convenient.